# Конвертер сайта Wordpress в мобильное приложение

Tags: javascript, php, android, wordpress, ios

Много что смотрел, читал, может кто подскажет, в какую сторону сделать выбор.
Все-таки какой инструмент для данной задачи более актуален?

Comment: PWA - самый простой и быстрый вариант.

Comment: @noname228 можно небольшое пояснение что это?